# Python Alternative to Old String Formatting

Tags: python

I just tried to use Python's `.format()` on text that contains many random curly braces.  It did not work because `.format()` tried to replace everything inside of single curly braces.  After doing some reading, it seems like I have three bad options:

1. Double all those random braces - this will look ugly
2. Use old string formatting `%` - this seems like it is going out of style
3. Import a template engine - this seems like overkill

What is the best option?  Is there a better choice?

Comment: Ask yourself one very important question. What do you need `.format()` for?

Comment: Is `%` really strongly depreciated? I can still see its user around me @@ .

Comment: You could insert `%s` and so on and `replace` it.

Comment: Perhaps .replace() is my best option?  I could edit the question to include that as well.

Comment: There is a [simple template engine](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings) in the standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple method :

```
>>> my_string = "Here come the braces : {a{b}c}d{e}f"
>>> additional_content = " : {}"
>>> additional_content = additional_content.format(42)
>>> my_string += additional_content
>>> my_string
'Here come the braces : {a{b}c}d{e}f : 42'
```

Also, you can create a function to double  the braces :

```
def double_brace(string):
    string = string.replace('{','{{')
    string = string.replace('}','}}')
    return string

my_string = "Here come the braces : {a{b}c}d{e}f"
my_string = double_brace(my_string)
my_string += " : {}"
my_string = my_string.format(42)
print(my_string)
```

Output :

```
>>> Here come the braces : {a{b}c}d{e}f : 42
```